Display Today in Android using Kotlin
I have to display "Today is xxxxxxx" in the text view. I got this working but the code shows warnings and suggestions in latest Android Studio (Kotlin).
Is there a better way to modify this code?
textview.text = """Today is ${SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(Date())}"""


Try this code it might resolve your problem
textview.text = "Today is ${LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault())}"


You need to add the following text to the strings.xml file:
<string name="text_today">Today is %1s</string>

Old:
val date = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(Date())
textview.text = getString(R.string.text_today, date)

In this section. When Locale is not specified, SimpleDateFormat will use the system default Locale (usually Local.US)
Update 1
val date = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
textview.text = getString(R.string.text_today, date)

In this new code snippet, Locale.getDefault() gets the device's default Locale (e.g. Locale.US for US English, Locale.VI for Vietnamese, etc.). The day name (Monday, Tuesday,...) will be displayed in the user's language on the device based on the current Local.
However, since your question is about wanting to disable the warning (Since you don't say what the warning is, I'm guessing it's a warning because you didn't set Local to SimpleFormatDate). So I suggest editing according to Update 1

This will still displays the same warning that the OP didn't want to have.

can you tell me about the warning content @tyg

If you mean the warning in SimpleDateFormat then you can review my answer. I just edited it.

You now have two variants, "Old" and "Update 1". Can you [edit] and describe in more detail when to use which variant? Or maybe one variant isn't needed anymore and can be removed?

I use the same code as mentioned in my question and import class and worked fine. Thanks everyone for your suggestions..!!
